# What's an easy way to implement a --quiet option in a python script

Tags: python

Am working on a command line python script - throughout the script, I have a lot of information I am `print`-ing to the terminal window so that I may follow along with what is happening.

Using `OptionParser` I want to add a `--quiet` option so I can silence all the output.  I am looking for a pythonic way to go about implementing this throughout the script so that I *don't* end up doing something like:

```
if not QUIET: # global variable set by OptionParser
    print " my output "
```

Am new to python and sure there is a better way.  Ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) and assign those things that should not be printed if `QUIET` a different log level.

**Edit:** [THC4K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815760/whats-an-easy-way-to-implement-a-quiet-option-in-a-python-script/1815802#1815802) shows an example of how to do this, assuming that all output should be silent if `QUIET` is set. Note that in Python 3 `from __future__ import print_function` is not necessary:

```
print = logging.info
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING if QUIET else logging.INFO,
                    format="%(message)s")
```

For for important output that should not be silenced by `--quiet`, define e.g. `iprint`:

```
iprint = logging.warning
```

Comment: I just looked at `logging` very briefly - does this mean that, in lieu of print, I could send text messages to a `logging` and then (in `__main__` decide whether the message was 'printed', saved to a file, or just silenced altogether?

Comment: thornomad - the answer is yes

Comment: @thornomad You configure a logger by either file, or code. So you could decide in main where the output would go.

Answer (score 16):

can silence **all** the output by running it as `python myscript.py > /dev/null`

change the output streams in the script:

```
if QUIET:
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'a')
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'a')
print(something)
```

use a different print function

```
from __future__ import print_function
if QUIET:
    def print(*args):
        pass
print(something)
```

use logging and loglevels

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(message)s")
print = logging.info
if QUIET:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

print(something)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just modify your output function based on whether the program is in quiet mode, so you only do the check once?

```
if QUIET:
    def DoOutput(stuff):
        pass
else:
    def DoOutput(stuff):
        print(stuff)
```

Or, you could of course put the check for `QUIET` inside your output function:

```
def DoOutput(stuff):
    if QUIET:
        print(stuff)
```

The situation that you've described is actually one of the reasons that Python 3 has changed `print` from a keyword to an actual function: people's large projects were becoming very dependent on `print` being a keyword, and then when it came time to modify how output was recorded, it required a massive refactoring; whereas when `print` is a proper function, you can just redefine it, so that `print(foo)` would output to a log file, for instance.  That's why it's better practice to wrap your output/logging in an actual function, rather than having `print` scattered about your script.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace stdout with a proxy that filters calls to write or writelines:

```
class FileProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, real_file, quiet_flag):
        self.real_file = real_file
        self.quiet_flag = quiet_flag

    def write(self, string):
        if not self.quiet_flag:
            self.real_file.write(string)

    def writelines(self, strings):
        if not self.quiet_flag:
            self.real_file.write(strings)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.file, name)

import sys
sys.stdout = FileProxy(sys.stdout, QUIET)
```

The advantage of this is that it is cross platform (unlike writing to /dev/null) and it will still work for print statements in third-party libraries that you do not have control over.
You could also refine it further to give more control over exactly what is written, e.g. to add a timestamp, or redirect print statements to the logging system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it quick and dirty and you want to get rid of *all* output then redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null. Put:

```
sys.stdout = open("/dev/null", "a")
sys.stderr = open("/dev/null", "a")
```

At the point where you detect --quiet.

Comment: That will probably destroy any chance of the program running on windows without cygwin, won't it? Windows doesn't have /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if QUIET:
   sys.stdout=open("/dev/null","w")
...
print 'my output'
```

On Windows,  use "nul" instead of "/dev/null"

Comment: It's better to use `os.devnull` - this will give you "/dev/null" or "nul" depending on the operating system.